# ADB is not responding in android studio 1.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

This problem arises since i have downloaded `genymotion`n my mac, everytime i try to run my application it says the `adb` not responding, kill adb and restart manually

I have tried all the possible solutions out there in web but it's not working for me can anyone please help me out with this

> **SOLVED THE FOLLOWING BY RE-DOWNLOADING THE SDK AND REDEFINING THE SDK PATH**

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Virus..**
Android Studio does not contain ADB, you need Android SDK for it (it is installed on first run of Android Studio 0.9.x and newer). ADB is located in sdk\platform-tools.

It's possible to add to PATH in Windows and use Terminal inside Android Studio only by command: "adb shell" and after use "su" get root shell.

locate SDK platform tools folder (eg: C:\android\sdk\platform-tools)
open Enviroment Variables in Windows (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)
add Platform tools to end of PATH (eg: ;C:\android\sdk\platform-tools)
reopen Android Studio
use Terminal with command: "adb shell"
Older Windows will maybe need reboot after change PATH variables.

EDIT: From new Android Studio is Android SDK separate outside Android Studio folder and is downloaded after first run of Android Studio. For more info: tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0814inbetachanne

Comment: I'm using mac so can please let know the solution for mac

Comment: Are you able to found Platform-tools folder in mac ? in that folder abd shell would be..

Comment: ya all those are there

Comment: ADB is now there on your computer. In order to set it up you will have to add the “export PATH=${PATH}:/Android-SDK/tools:/platform-tools” line on the end of the ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile configuration files
If that file is not there you can anytime create it by choosing “~/.profile”.

Comment: you have to export PATH of adb to get in local... just like you add PATH of JDK and GENYMOTION...